# Confusing matrix product properties question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a strange question in the quiz:

**Which of the following holds true?**

**a)** *Product of two non-diagonal matrices is a non-diagonal matrix.*

**b)** *Product of two matrices in an upper-triangular form can be a matrix in a non-upper-tirangular form.*

**c)** *Product of two symmetric matrices is a symmetric matrix.*

**d)** *Product of two square matrices can be a nonsquare matrix.*

I know that a) is not true since zero matrix is a diagonal and we can take some nilpotent matrix with an index of nilpotence $2$ and get a zero metrix.

c) holds true only for commuting matrices.

d) is obviously wrong.

But now comes b). What to do here? I can't find any example where you can magically change zeroes into something else, so that the matrix becomes non-upper-triangular. Any ideas?

Comment: The product of upper triangular matrices is upper triangular. Same idea for lower triangular.

Comment: And I should add that there *might* be a mistake indeed. It wouldn't be for the first time...

Comment: If you think about how matrix multiplication is done, you'll see what happens when you multiply two upper-triangular matrices.

Comment: You’re trying too hard for a counterexample for (a). Just take any invertible non-diagonal matrix and its inverse.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ is in upper triangular if whenever $i>j$, we have $A_{ij}=0$.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are upper triangular, let $C=AB$.

Let $i>j$,

$$C_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} A_{ik}B_{kj}+\sum_{k=i}^{n} A_{ik}B_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1} 0 \cdot B_{kj}+\sum_{k=i}^{n} A_{ik}\cdot 0=0$$

As a practice, try to prove a corresponding result for lower triangular matrices.

Comment: A proof by induction (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/440092) is also possible.